# QEMU/KVM guest VM cannot resolve DNS hostnames or SSH/ping from host

Tags: domain-name-system, centos, ssh, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I have a QEMU/KVM-based virtual machine with CentosOS 6.4 that cannot fully connect to the Internet. I can ping IP addresses (ex. `ping 8.8.8.8` works successfully), but domain names are not resolved (ex. `ping google.com` returns `ping: unknown host google.com`).

The guest has a static IP assigned to it, and I am using the default (NAT-based) network:

```
<network>
  <name>default</name>
  <uuid>8c257186-7af4-4e19-a086-27f50f692af6</uuid>
  <forward mode='nat'/>
  <bridge name='virbr0' stp='on' delay='0'/>
  <mac address='52:54:00:d6:62:2d'/>
  <ip address='192.168.122.1' netmask='255.255.255.0'>
    <dhcp>
      <range start='192.168.122.2' end='192.168.122.254'/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>
```

`/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` is not present on the VM; and neither of the `resolvconf`, `nslookup`, `systemctl`, `host`, `hostnamectl`, or `nmcli` programs are installed, so the ability to run network setting diagnostics is limited.

I’ve tried the following:

- Editing `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` by adding `DNS1=8.8.8.8`, `DNS2=8.8.4.4` and `PEERDNS=yes`. After rebooting, this created `/etc/resolv.conf`, which was not originally present.
- Replacing "hosts: files dns" with "hosts: files dns nisplus nis" in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, then rebooting.
- Following [this guide](https://amoldighe.github.io/2017/12/20/kvm-networking/) to create a host-only network.
- Following [this guide](https://apiraino.github.io/qemu-bridge-networking/) to create a virtual bridge via qemu-bridge-helper.
- (As an aside, I attempted to create a fileshare between the guest and host via [this guide](https://cialu.net/qemu-kvm-on-ubuntu-and-sharing-files-between-host-and-guests/), but this requires 9p, a filesystem that CentOS 6 is apparently not compatible with.)

But with each attempt, the host still cannot SSH into/ping the guest, nor can the guest resolve domain names. Any help with accomplishing either of these two steps (**the host can SSH into the guest**; **the guest is fully connected to the Internet**) would be very much appreciated.

Here are some file contents/command line outputs that might be helpful. Happy to provide more information.

Contents of `/etc/resolv.conf` (Guest):

```
options edns0 trust-ad
; generated by /sbin/dhclient-script
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Output of `ip a` (Guest):

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever


2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:7b:6c:27 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.92/22 brd 192.168.123.255 scope global eth0
    inet6 fe80::5054ﬀfe7b:6c27/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Output of `ssh 192.168.122.92` (Host):

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.122.92 port 22: Connection refused
```

Output of `ping 192.168.122.92` (Host):

```
PING 192.168.122.92 (192.168.122.92) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.122.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Port Unreachable
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
From 192.168.122.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Port Unreachable
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
From 192.168.122.1 icmp_seq=3 Destination Port Unreachable
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
From 192.168.122.1 icmp_seq=4 Destination Port Unreachable
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
^C
--- 192.168.122.92 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, +4 errors, 100% packet loss, time 3065ms
```

**EDIT 1**

Contents of `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` (Guest):

```
DEVICE=eth0
HWADDR=52:54:00:7B:6C:27
TYPE=Ethernet
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
BOOTPRONTO=none
IPADDR=192.168.122.92
NETMASK=255.255.252.0
GATEWAY=192.168.122.1
DNS1=8.8.8.8
DNS2=8.8.4.4
PEERDNS=yes
```

**EDIT 2**

Output of `iptables-save` (Host):

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Mon Jan  3 22:03:26 2022
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [86972:77359835]
:INPUT ACCEPT [86966:77359331]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [6:504]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [87805:9060728]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [69226:7583136]
:LIBVIRT_PRT - [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -j LIBVIRT_PRT
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j CHECKSUM --checksum-fill
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Jan  3 22:03:26 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Mon Jan  3 22:03:26 2022
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [4:1038]
:INPUT ACCEPT [3:954]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [19614:1550200]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [1032:73142]
:LIBVIRT_PRT - [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -j LIBVIRT_PRT
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 224.0.0.0/24 -j RETURN
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 255.255.255.255/32 -j RETURN
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p tcp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p udp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Jan  3 22:03:26 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Mon Jan  3 22:03:26 2022
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [86966:77359331]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [69220:7582632]
:LIBVIRT_FWI - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_FWO - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_FWX - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_INP - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_OUT - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j LIBVIRT_INP
-A FORWARD -j LIBVIRT_FWX
-A FORWARD -j LIBVIRT_FWI
-A FORWARD -j LIBVIRT_FWO
-A OUTPUT -j LIBVIRT_OUT
-A LIBVIRT_FWI -d 192.168.122.0/24 -o virbr0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_FWI -o virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A LIBVIRT_FWO -s 192.168.122.0/24 -i virbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_FWO -i virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A LIBVIRT_FWX -i virbr0 -o virbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Jan  3 22:03:26 2022
```

**EDIT 3**

Output of `sudo iptables-save` (Guest):

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Thu Jan 6 05:53:35 2022
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Jan 6 05:53:35 2022
```

Comment: > inet 192.168.122.92/**22** brd 192.168.123.255 scope global eth0 Looks fishy to me. Can we see `cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` ? It looks like you have an incorrect net mask on your guest. > NETMASK=255.255.252.0

Comment: > inet 192.168.122.92/**22** brd 192.168.123.255 scope global eth0

Looks fishy to me. 

Can we see `cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` ?

Comment: Thanks @Jacobyoby . I added more info above.

Comment: your net masks do not match. Is this intentional?

Comment: It's not intentional. I've set `NETMASK=255.255.255.0` in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` to match with the virtual network. I now get `inet 192.168.122.92/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global eth0` under `eth0` in `ip a` in the guest. But DNS still does not resolve domain names, and the guest IP cannot be reached via SSH/ping in the host.

Comment: did you disable firewalld for testing?

Comment: @Jacobyoby @AlexD Not firewalld, but it's likely due to these two rules in `iptables`: `-A LIBVIRT_FWI -o virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable` and `-A LIBVIRT_FWO -i virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable` (more details above). However, I (temporarily) removed them, rebooted the guest VM, and still get the same errors.

Comment: please add a rule to allow inbound SSH on port 22 to iptables.

Comment: I added two new rules to iptables in the guest: `sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT` and `sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`. I also added `sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT` and `sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT` to the host. However, I'm getting the same errors. Am I missing anything?

Comment: can you disable iptables for testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following error messages from `ping` indicate that the communication is blocked by a firewall.

```
Destination Port Unreachable
ping: sendmsg: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: It turns out that the VPN was the issue. Either turning off the VPN, or allowing local network sharing within the VPN, fixed the issue. I'm now able to ping/SSH into the guest VM successfully. Thank you, everyone!